# Are there any other interesting functions such as $e^x$ whose derivative and integral are the same?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, soft-question

$e^x$ is interesting, but does anybody know if there are other functions that behave in an interesting way when taking the derivative/integral?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by 'interesting', though in most cases, yes.

Comment: Well, there are close relatives, like $\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}$ and $\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}$, where the derivative bounces back and forth, and $\sin x$, $\cos x$ which exhibit similar but more complicated behaviour.

Comment: Any function that is the solution of an interesting differential equations ...

Comment: Is $y=0$ interesting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constants are annihilated by derivatives, and polynomials are *eventually* annihilated by derivatives. Functions supported on null sets are annihilated by integrals.

Comment: (Also, "Annihilated by Integrals" would be a pretty good name for a Christian metal/nerdcore crossover band. The debut album: *Cantor Dust*.)

Answer (score 9):

Let $y$ be such a function and $z$ be an antiderivative of $y$, that is $y = z'$, then you want to find solutions to the differential equation $z'' = z$. This is a second order constant coefficient linear ODE which has solutions $z = Ae^x + Be^{-x}$ where $A$ and $B$ are constants, so $y = z' = Ae^x - Be^{-x}$. Alternatively, we can write such function as $y = C\cosh x + D\sinh x$ where $C$ and $D$ are constants.